# What is the Post-fix and Prefix form of this two infix expression, See the details please?

Tags: logic

There is two infix expression i mentioned below. Now i want to justify whether my answer is correct or not. So please tell me the correct post-fix and prefix form of this

two infix expression.

1. A*B+(C*D/E)*F+(G^H)
2. 1*2/3+(4–5^6)+7–8

My solution for both of them are

1. AB*CDE/*+F*GH^+
   and
2. 123/*456^-+78-+

If I am wrong then please give me the correct answer and enlightened me.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax

Comment: If you have doubts about your own solutions, why don't you include them in your question, in order for us to verify them? To me, it looks like you are cheating and asking us to do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

For the first,
in postfix,
assuming ^ before */ before +-
and * and / are left-to-right,

a b * c d * e / f * + g h ^ +

Comment: An explanation of how priority is being assigned (in the absence of parentheses) would make such a reply more useful to future Readers.

Comment: @hardmath: Such a comment could come only from one who doesn't know what "postfix" means. :) Postfix has no priority. Future readers, if they stumble upon this question, already know what "postfix" involves, otherwise they wouldn't convert formulae from infix to postfix.

Comment: @AkexM: True, postfix has no parentheses, but I  refer to the poor wording of the Question.  If you tackle an ambiguous problem, some note about your choice of interpretation is key.

Answer (score 1):

One way to attack these problems is to begin by completely parenthesizing the expression, so that there is a pair of parentheses around each pair of operands and the operation performed on them. If you do this to the second infix expression, you get this:

$$\Bigg(\bigg(\Big(\big((1\cdot 2)/3\big)+\big(4-(5^6)\big)\Big)+7\bigg)-8\Bigg)$$

Now work from the inside out. If your goal is prefix notation, replace $(x\oplus y)$ (where $\oplus$ stands for any operation) with $\oplus xy$; if your goal is postfix notation, replace $(x\oplus y)$ with $xy\oplus$. I’ll do prefix notation. The innermost parenthesized expressions are $(1\cdot 2)$ and $(5^6)$, which I can think of as $(5\text{^}6)$ to give it a visible operator; these are replaced by $\cdot12$ and $\text{^}56$, respectively, so that we now have

$$\Bigg(\bigg(\Big(\big(\underbrace{\cdot12}/3\big)+\big(4-\underbrace{\text{^}56}\big)\Big)+7\bigg)-8\Bigg)\;,\tag{1}$$

where the expressions within $\underbrace{\text{underbraces}}$ are now to be thought of as single entities, on a par with $7$ and $8$.

The innermost parenthesized expression in $(1)$ are $(\underbrace{\cdot12}/3)$ and $(4-\underbrace{\text{^}56})$, with operations $/$ and $-$, so they are replaced by $/\cdot123$ and $-4\text{^}56$, respectively. This changes $(1)$ to

$$\Bigg(\bigg(\Big(\underbrace{/\cdot123}+\underbrace{-4\text{^}56}\Big)+7\bigg)-8\Bigg)\;,\tag{2}$$

an expression of the form $\Big(\big((a+b)+c\big)-d\Big)$.

$(2)$ has only one innermost parenthesized expression, $\Big(\underbrace{/\cdot123}+\underbrace{-4\text{^}56}\Big)$, which becomes

$$+/\cdot123-4\text{^}56\;,$$

so that $(2)$ becomes

$$\Bigg(\bigg(\underbrace{+/\cdot123-4\text{^}56}+7\bigg)-8\Bigg)\;,\tag{3}$$

of the form $\big((a+b)-c\big)$. The innermost parenthesized expression is $\bigg(\underbrace{+/\cdot123-4\text{^}56}+7\bigg)$, with operator $+$; it becomes

$$++/\cdot123-4\text{^}567\;,$$

and $(3)$ becomes

$$\Bigg(\underbrace{++/\cdot123-4\text{^}567}-8\Bigg)\;.\tag{4}$$

One more step of the same kind then turns $(4)$ into the desired prefix form,

$$-++/\cdot123-4\text{^}5678\;.$$

Had I been going for postfix form, I’d have dealt with the seven operators in the original infix expression in exactly the same order (i.e., starting with $1\cdot 2$ and $5^6$), but I’d have put the operator *after* the operands each time; the final postfix expression is

$$12\cdot3/456\text{^}-+7+8-\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

See the Wikipedia article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm?wprov=sfla1
which gives an easy method for conversion from infix to postfix.
Postfix is sometimes called "reverse Polish" representation.